# User Authentication - Error Log In

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to authenticate an user from a Log In form which asks for user and password.

Register form is working well and I'm including the password in the database by this:

```
$user_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_pass']);
$user_pass = sha1($security_pass.$user_pass);
```

Then, I'm checking the user and the password (after checking they're no empty):

```
$user_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$user_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_pass']);
$user_pass = sha1($security_pass.$user_pass);

$query = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user='".$user_name."'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if ($result['pass']!=$user_pass){
            echo "Incorrect login";
            echo $sql;
            echo $result;
}else{
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
            $_SESSION["user_name"] = $row['user'];
            echo "Correct login!";
}
```

But it's always returning "Incorrect login", "Resource id # 3" and "Array".

I've tried to put this part like this too:

```
$query = "SELECT user, pass FROM users WHERE user='$user_name'";
```

I can't find the error! Help please!

Comment: Try `WHERE user='".$user_name."' AND pass='".$user_pass."'`

Comment: You do no error detection and handling _at all_, but you ask here what the error might be. Why don't you ask your mysql server (by its php client) if there was an error? You _always_ should implement error handling, otherwise you are flying in the dark when programming.

Comment: Why do you call `mysql_fetch_array` a second time in your `else`?

Comment: You should use `mysql_num_rows()` instead, to check for a match. Better still, you shouldn't even be using any of this code.

Comment: why dont you echo `$result['pass']` and echo `$user_pass` and see if they equal or they are wrong ?? l ike that you debug it yourself and see which is wrong. But dont Echo me :)

Comment: Try with this to check if there is an error : `$sql = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

First, mysql should no longer be used as your database connection driver. You should be utilizing either mysqli or pdo. If you choose to stay with mysql your problem probably is with mysql_fetch_array(). You did not specify for it to return an associative array which therefore the array key 'pass' would be invalid.